# Makefile error: No rule to make target

Tags: makefile

```
SOURCES = server.c

TARGET = Server

CC = gcc

all: $(SOURCES) $(TARGET) 


$(CC) $(SOURCES) -o $(TARGET) 

clean:


rm -rf $(TARGET)
```

Above is the Makefile of my web server. Though server.c file is in the directory this gives the fallowing error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Server', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

What is the mistake I've made and how to solve it.

Comment: Does your makefile really look like the above? If not, please edit until the two match. If it does, read up on makefile syntax.

Comment: ya this is my makefile. This gives me the above error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your makefile got garbled somewhere between your machine and the post, but there is a simple fix that I think will work:

```
all: $(SOURCES)
```

That will (probably) solve the problem and make the error go away-- if that's all you want then you can stop reading. But *there are still things wrong with this makefile*, so we can make some more improvements.

First, a little adjustment to make it match what I think your makefile really says:

```
SOURCES = server.c

TARGET = Server

CC = gcc

all: $(SOURCES) $(TARGET)
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) -o $(TARGET) 

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET)
```

The first three lines and the `clean` rule are all right, we'll ignore those. Now we give `TARGET` its own rule and straighten out the prerequisites:

```
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) -o $(TARGET)
```

Now we make `all` PHONY (since it doesn't really make a file called "all"), and introduce automatic variables to make the `TARGET` rule more robust and less redundant:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

There's more to learn if your codebase gets more complicated, but that'll do for now.

Answer (score 2):

just do "make clean" to clean all links, then run make again. Everything should be good.

Answer (score 0):

My issues was I had the name and the command on the same line. Make: sure you are using tabs and not spaces. (no pun intended)

BEFORE (Broken)

```
build: docker build...
```

AFTER

```
build:
        docker build...
```