# Makefile produces error "No rule to make target"

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I've tried to fix this using the other two most relevant topics: 
[Makefile error: No rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874780/makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)
[Makefile: No rule to make target. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239563/makefile-no-rule-to-make-target-stop)

But neither seem to solve my issue.

I'm unsure where my code went wrong, as my instructor verified that the code works on his end.

The code for my makefile is:

```
TARGET  = demo
FILES   = test.c
OBJS    = $(FILES:.c=.o)
ASMS    = $(FILES:.c=.s)

all:    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $@ $^

%.o:    %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

%.s:    %.c
    gcc -S -masm=intel $< -o $@

asm:    $(ASMS)

run:    $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(ASMS)
```

However, when I attempt to do "make run" it produces the result

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'run'. Stop.
```

As seen here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKwDO.png)

The actual code to my program that I'm trying to compile is only 4 lines long. I don't think it's the reason for the issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *msg = "Exam Lab 1";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}
```

Here's the contents of the directory I'm running `make` from:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/r5EnwHj.png]

Comment: Make sure the indented lines for each recipe are using only tab characters, not spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Completely forgot that makefiles rely on tabs, however I'm running into the problem still.

http://i.imgur.com/wioJc37.png

Comment: What are the contents of the directory you're running `make` from?  The makefile (named either `Makefile` or `makefile`) and the .c files should be there.

Comment: Also, are you using GNU make? (run `make -v` to find out).

Comment: Yeah, all the files are in the same directory, and I'm using GNU Make 4.1. http://i.imgur.com/r5EnwHj.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your makefile doesn't have the correct name.

By default, `make` looks for a file named either `makefile` or `Makefile`.  Yours is named `Makefile.txt`, so `make` can't find it.

Either change the name to `makefile` or `Makefile`, or use the `-f` option to specify the makefile name, ex. `make -f Makefile.txt`.

Comment: Note that it can also happen when running make in the wrong directory; where there is no `Makefile` file.

Answer (score 2):

From the image you've provided it's clear that you've named the file `Makefile.txt`.  As @dbush says, the makefile *MUST* be named either `Makefile` or `makefile`.  Those are the only file names make looks for by default.

Either that or you have to run `make -f Makefile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `Makefile` depends on another external `*.a` library file to be already built and exist.

I mean, in Makefile-world even said external dependency is called "target".

Hence, there really is "no rule to make target" ;-)